# What's the relationship between UINavigationController and UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm becoming confused these days using UINavigationController;
I'd like to customize the UINavigationController,changing its background image and adding buttons;
I tried this in 2 projects. In the first I did this by using

`self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;`
but in the secoenter code herend this method doesn't work.I have to use

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customItem;
```

if a ViewController is a rootViewController of a NavigationController,it has two properties:

```
self.navigationController
self.navigationItem
```

and the Navigation has 3 properties:

```
self.navigationController.navigationController
self.navigationController.navigationBar
self.navigationController.navigationItem
```

why the NavigationController also has a property NavigationController?

why sometimes I use

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem
```

but sometimes I have to use

```
self.navigationItem
```

I'm really confused.

Comment: `secoenter code herend` - you know Herend is a small village in Hungary, famous of its porcelain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
why the NavigationController also has a property NavigationController?
```

Because it inherits from `UIViewController`, which has this property.

As a general rule, you don't want to directly manipulate the properties of the navigation controller enclosing your view controller (these properties include the navigation controller's navigation item and navigation bar). Modify `self.navigationItem.whateverPropertyYouWannaSet`; the properties of the navigation item are read by the navigation controller upon pushing your view controller onto its stack, and it will setup its **own** navigation bar according to these properties.

Comment: but how to customize the background color if I don't use the `self.navigationController.navigationBar` property?

Comment: @user1356799 you can customize the background color that way, just not the properties (e. g. rightBarButtonItem) which don't require direct access.